# get Hard Disk information like serial key without System.Management

Tags: c#, .net, system

How can i access the hard disk info like serial number without using the

```
System.Management
```

class so i can map it to another environments other than windows (like mac,linux)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) (available in Mono) for basic information (but it doesn't include SN IIRC).

Comment: yes i know sir, but "DriveInfo" is not helpful at all ! 
thank you